# Target a DIV without an ID or CLASS

Tags: jquery, css

Using jQuery, is it possible to target the following without a selector:

```
<div style="background-color:#9AAEDB; padding:4px"></div>
```

If so, how, as I basically need to hide this div for a particular scenario?

Comment: Just give it an id or class. Another option is: if you can get its parent or child reliably, then you can also select it.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What id your requirement?

Comment: You can also target it by specifying a `name` attribute on it.

Comment: Testing for a `style` attribute is tricky and error-prone. See: http://jsfiddle.net/gwm7n/ Note, the actual attribute values being tested are arbitrary.

Comment: `//div[@style="background-color: blah blah blah"]`?

Comment: _"without a selector"_ - No. You need _some_ selector, even if it is to select the parent element and then find the div as the nth child of that parent. Or select a child of the div and traverse up to the div. Easiest to just give it an id.

Comment: have you tried targeting it with style attribute. I know this is ethically incorrect solution but since it is your requirement.

Comment: I don't get it. How do you target an element without a selector...?

Comment: @TejasvaDhyani - "ethically incorrect"? Not sure that I'd go that far...

Comment: It's not sitting in a vacuum: it's the child of some other element and you could get from the parent node. But, if you control the code, WHY would you not not give it an id or a class in the first place?

Comment: Can you tell us your DOM structure? Like where exactly your DIV is located. That would reduce the number of wild guesses made to help you figure this out...

For your current question - YES it is possible to select a div without ID or class... For more info be specific

Comment: @BoltClock - You are obviously not imaginative enough... `:P`

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Nah... I think I'm just *really* sleep-deprived :(

Comment: @nnnnnn try out this http://jsfiddle.net/gwm7n/1/

Comment: @BoltClock - That is *sooo* contributory to the experience.

Comment: Guys, I should've pointed out that I don't have access to change this style, so this being the reason for my question.

Comment: @BoltClock is right, you cant SELECT anything without SELECTor... :P
JaredFarrish : anything that selects is selector

PS : Enough of this philosophical ranting :D

Comment: Well, at least someone took me seriously.

Comment: @tonsils : Can you please specify where exactly your DIV is located?
That will help us give your accurate answer :)

Comment: Apologies for the question, silly as it may be but please delete or close. Thanks.

Comment: I did the first close vote some time ago, but honestly, if you'd put some effort -- e.g. show the html around that element, specify some requirements (which don't include selecting without a selector) etc. It'd be a very answerable question.

Comment: @Fabrício Thanks for that but I guess there is no point now.

Comment: Well yeah, but if you don't find a solution before this question gets closed you can always make a new question including more specific info -- surely you'd have a satisfying answer in seconds. `=]`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$("div[style='background-color:#9AAEDB; padding:4px']")
```

to select your required div

Comment: It is unlikely this would work reliably in all browsers because it relies on exact ordering and spacing in the style attribute which is not a standard.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use an id for selecting the div. You can target the div by using

```
$('div')
```

However, it will target all the divs included in your page. So, if you want to target a single div, it's better to use an ID or a class.

Answer (score 0):

$('div') will select all the div's, and I believe $('div.div') would select the child of another div - this would work as dynamic for different scenarios, just edit to your needs.

Using the "id" and "class" attributes in your HTML tags will make it far more efficient, but the method I just spoke about does come in handy sometimes.

Comment: `$.('div.div')` wouldn't work - need to remove the dot from just after the `$`. Regarding the selector, `'div.div'` would select all divs with class "div". `'div > div'` would select all divs that are the immediate child of a div. And finally `'div div'` would select all divs that are descendants of a div..

Answer (score 0):

You can target that div either from parent element and mark which child is that div of parent element, or using some selector. That selector might be id, class, or even title, rel... Or, you can target that specific div based on his children.