# Targeting a specific element in CSS which has no id or class specified to it

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am often stuck on this problem where I have a parent element with an "ID" and a group of child elements which don't have any "ID" or "CLASS" to be target specifically.

Sometimes, I really don't have an option to specify an "ID" or "Class" to an element so I can just easily target the element. I also don't have a privilege to use javascript to override. So I am really just stuck using CSS to style it.

Are there approaches in CSS where I can target a specific element?

See my Example Problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/jUeMB/

I just want to isolate "Item 4" and highlight it. This is the best I can do but It's also wrong because It's targeting "Item 5",should ONLY highlight "Item 4".

Thanks.

Comment: Fixed problem can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/jUeMB/1/. answered by user1538100 and bertl

Comment: Oddly enough there was a jQuery selector version of this question a short while ago, except the OP didn't really want a selector: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715398/target-a-div-without-an-id-or-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The n'th child selector is what you are looking for. http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Comment: Great and Thanks! This is exactly what im looking for... But I was also expecting it may not be widely supported on IE. I wish It somehow supported at least IE8.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
#list_item li:nth-child(4)
```

And similarly also for the table and div.
Look [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild) for browser suppoport.